# How to add a song to jPlayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I want to add a song to jPlayer when the user clicks on a link. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add to the protoype object.

```
Playlist.prototype

addMedia: function(media) {
  this.playlist.push(media);
  this.displayPlaylist();
}
```

Then use it like:

```
myPlaylist.addMedia( {
  name:"Tempered Song",
  mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3",
  oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.ogg",
  poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/poster/Miaow_132x132.jpg"
});
```

Comment: That looks good. I need more information though. I don't even know where to place these snippets in my code. I'm a total newbie.

Comment: Where do I place the first snippet? And where do I name my playlist myPlaylist for the second snippet? Where does the second snippet go?

Comment: Can you post the code you already have so I can tell you? Does this link help explain? http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-7-audio/

Comment: This is my HTML http://pastebin.com/yi1kPDh5 and this my main.js http://pastebin.com/BVdzbRXM

Comment: Try putting the first part in the main.js and the second part inbetween <script> in the HTML document?

Comment: That gives me an error for `Playlist.prototype addMedia: function(media) {
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
`

Comment: Ok, that's just a syntax error, so there must be a stray , or bracket in your code somewhere. Post it to pastebin again or test the javascript using Firebug?

Comment: Ok put the JQuery I gave you inside the document.ready final bracket and test in firebug as all it is is a syntax error, make sure you haven't got too many opening/closing brackets etc.

Comment: @lifetimes  Unresolved function or method `displayPlayList()`